# Laravel 5 can not access atributes from model

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I got a slight issue,for some reason I'm unable to access my attributes from a relationship model.

I keep getting the same error, **'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$season'**

I have been staring at this all day and I couldn't find a solution for it.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Show;
use App\Episode;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function test(){

         $shows = Show::where('active',1)->get();
        foreach ($shows as $show) {
            if($show->active == 1 && $show->airday == date('N'))
            {
                echo 'test';
                $episode = $show->episodes()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->get();
                \Debugbar::info($episode);
                //this is the line where he gives me
                echo('New episodes avaible, Season '.$episode->season.' Episode '.$episode->episode.' From '.$show->name);
                //end error
            }
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Although if I do a print out of the $episode variable I can clearly see the properties I wish to access.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#150
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Episode {#241
      #table: "episodes"
      +timestamps: true
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:6 [
        "id" => "6"
        "show_id" => "6"
        "season" => "3"
        "episode" => "15"
        "created_at" => "2016-02-07 11:45:53"
        "updated_at" => "2016-02-07 11:45:53"
      ]
      #original: array:6 [
        "id" => "6"
        "show_id" => "6"
        "season" => "3"
        "episode" => "15"
        "created_at" => "2016-02-07 11:45:53"
        "updated_at" => "2016-02-07 11:45:53"
      ]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
```

At the moment I'm clueless whats wrong with the code.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `->take(1)->get()` you're telling Eloquent (the builder, really) to give you back a `Collection` object with 1 item in it.

So when you're trying to access your `$season` property, you're actually trying to access it on a Collection object and not the Model that you think.

You can do a couple of things:

1. You can replace your `->take(1)->get()` call with `->first()`,
2. or you can treat your current `$episode` variable as a collection, and retrieve the actual episode you care about by accessing `$episode[0]`,
3. or you can call `first` on your current `$episode` variable (`$episode = $episode->first()`) to get the first model object within it.

Comment: Hey Jim, thanks for your answer, that makes sense, thanks!